# Save to Gallery - Android

Tags: android

I've a strange (and oddly specific) issue with saving to the gallery on Android.

A bit of background: The app I'm developing needs to be able to save images to the gallery, which has been well discussed on here before. However, there's a specific requirement for this project which is I need to be able to tag it with a specific date/time.

I've tried several methods to get this to work correctly and so far the best I have is a workaround.

What I'm doing at the moment is generating the image, saving it to a file and setting the created date in the EXIF data. I then open the Google Photos app and it shows up in the gallery, showing the correct date and time and is in the correct place within the gallery.

The issue with this however, is that it doesn't automatically show in any other gallery software (for example, the OEM gallery apps that may be shipped with a given device), nor does it show if the Google Photos app is open at the time of saving; It must be closed and relaunched in order for it to show.

Now, if I run a media scan it ignores the EXIF data and the image shows up as the last image created.

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
    static class InsertImageObj{
        public String url;
        public long id;
    }
    public static InsertImageObj insertImage(Bitmap source,
                                           String title, long time) {
        String path = createDirectoryAndSaveFile(source, title, time);

        String stringUrl = path;
        InsertImageObj retVal = new InsertImageObj();
        retVal.url = stringUrl;
        return retVal;
    }

    private static String createDirectoryAndSaveFile(Bitmap imageToSave, String fileName, long dateTime) { 
        File directory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM); //DCIM = Digital Camera Image. This is where camera photos go!
        if (!directory.exists()) {
            directory.mkdirs();
        }
        File file = new File(directory, fileName);
        if (file.exists()) {
            file.delete();
        }
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            imageToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(file.getAbsolutePath());
            ei.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME, convertToExifDateTime(dateTime));
            ei.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME_ORIGINAL, convertToExifDateTime(dateTime));
            ei.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME_DIGITIZED, convertToExifDateTime(dateTime));
            ei.saveAttributes();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return file.getAbsolutePath();
    }
    private static String convertToExifDateTime(long timestamp) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
        return sdf.format(new Date(timestamp));
    }
```

I've also tried running `setLastModified` on the file (which doesn't work, OS permissions or something or other) and using a `MediaScannerConnection` instance to scan the individual file once it has been saved. The latter, however causes the system to ignore the date/time tags in the Exif data.
I also tried inserting the image into the gallery via a `ContentResolver` instance and setting the `DATE_ADDED` and `DATE_TAKEN` fields, again to no avail.

Is there something really, really obvious I've missed here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save your image in the media store provider

Use this function

```
public static void imageToGallery(Context context, String fileName) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());  
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, fileName);
    context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
}
```

So, after saving your image, call `imageToGallery`.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm pretty sure I've tried this approach before and it ignored the DATE_TAKEN. I'm not using the current time, but a different, arbitrary time.

Comment: You can use your date, the important thing here is to save your file to the media store provider.

Comment: Turns out this is the solution. I've no idea why it didn't work previously, although it works now so I'll ask no more questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Images are only visible in gallery apps if they are added to the android-media-db.

You can ask `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(...)` to add the new photo-file to the android-media-db.

On some androiddevices (but not on all) the mediascanner starts automatically.

Also note: you should save the new photo as ".../DCIM/myApp/myPhotoName.jpg" instead of ".../DCIM/myPhotoName.jpg"

Comment: Yep, although as per my question, scanFile ignores the datetime tags in the EXIF data.
I'm also saving directly to the DCIM directory, not a subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function. Its working for me!

```
private void galleryAddPic() {
        File f = new File(imageFilePath);

        try {
            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getActivity().getContentResolver(),
                    f.getAbsolutePath(), f.getName(), null);
            getActivity().sendBroadcast(new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(f)));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```